# Can Jenkins master connect to a slave node in a private subnet?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-web-services

We've got a Linux Jenkins master node  set up in AWS behind a load balancer and I'm attempting to connect to Windows slave nodes in private subnets.  Is this possible?  The Jenkins URL is accessible when I RDP into each server, but when I attempt to configure the node using "Launch agent from browser" an error occurs.

```
hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to <JenkinsURL>:39057 (retrying:4)
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to gpa-jenkins- 
prod.aws.baxter.com:39057
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoint.java:242)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.connect(Engine.java:686)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:547)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:469)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoint.java:203)
    ... 3 more
```

What could be the source for this refusal?

Comment: Could you explain why the jenkins-master does not reside in the same private subnet as well?

Answer (score 1):

As described in Jenkins documentation https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/security/#jnlp-tcp-port, you need to configure:

1. Jenkins to use fixed TCP port for JNLP agent, for instance 39057
2. AWS loadbalancer to listen on port 39057 and forward it to Jenkins on same port